# dnvm upgrade command not working for ASP.NET 5 command line tools

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-4.6

While trying step 3 of [Installing ASP.NET 5 on Windows](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html), I am getting the following error on the command prompt of Windows 7. I have VS2015 Professional installed: `PowerShell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0):

After I restarted my Windows 7, the command worked. Following is the output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>dnvm upgrade
Determining latest version
Downloading dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1 from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
Installing to C:\Users\myUserName\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1
Adding C:\Users\myUserName\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin to pr
ocess PATH
Adding C:\Users\myUserName\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin to us
er PATH
Setting alias 'default' to 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1'
```